# Animating SVG across the screen continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, velocity.js

I am trying to animated an SVG object to go across the screen continuously like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/PPVda/

However I couldn't get it to work. My guess is because SVG doesn't work with CSS .animate.

So I tried to use velocity.js instead.

I have manage to re-position my svg using:

`$.Velocity.hook($("#39aa995f-2ba5-4316-9c79-ef5b3d58d63d")[0], "translateX", "-300px")`;

And translating it using:

```
$("#39aa995f-2ba5-4316-9c79-ef5b3d58d63d").velocity({
    translateX: 4000,
  }, 9000);
```

To make it a continuously, I used this:

```
setTimeout(test(), 9000)
```

However, it doesn't run continuously.

Any help would be great! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$("#39aa995f-2ba5-4316-9c79-ef5b3d58d63d").velocity({
  translateX: [4000, -600],
},{
  duration: 9000,
  easing: "lnear",
 delay: 0
});
```

https://davidwalsh.name/svg-animation

I don't recommend using callbacks for looping with SVG's

Comment: Thanks man it works! Alright, I will explore other ways for looping SVG. Just curious, why don't you recommend so? Does it has something to do with performance issues?